# How can I concatenate blobs?

Tags: python, sqlite, group-by, buffer, blob

is there a way to aggregate BLOB (binary) of two records in sqlite, when using a GROUP BY.

Already tried withouth success:

1) GROUP_CONCAT function from sqlite Documentation but it doesn't work for BLOB data type, it returns only 1 Byte even if the 2 BLOBs were larger than that.

```
 SELECT id, GROUP_CONCAT(blob_col)
 FROM table
 GROUP BY id
```

2) Defining own SQL function via Python Sqlite3 "create_aggregate" function

```
import sqlite3

class BlobConcat:

    def __init__(self):
        self.count = buffer("")

    def step(self, value):
        print str(value)
        self.count += value[:]

    def finalize(self):
        return self.count

con = sqlite3.connect(dbPath)

con.create_aggregate("BLOB_CONCAT", 1, BlobConcat)

sql = """SELECT id, BLOB_CONCAT(blob_col)
         FROM table
         GROUP BY id"""
```

Also returning only 1 byte.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLite has no built-in mechanism to concatenate blobs.

You *can* write a user-defined function (aggregate or not) to do this.
The problem with your class is that `return self.count` returns a `str` object, which is interpreted as a string, not a blob. You have to explicitly convert it into a buffer:

```
class BlobConcat:
    ...
    def finalize(self):
        return buffer(self.count)
```